# Cascading filters at different sampling rates

Tags: filter-design, sampling

We are currently designing a type 2 compensator $G_1$ (1 pole at the origin, 1 zero and 1 pole) to stabilize a power factor correction (PFC) circuitry. The crossover frequency is low - 2-3 Hz - and the compensator is implemented using a biquad structure sampling at 10 kHz. For ripple filtering reasons, this filter will be followed by another low-pass 50-Hz filter $G_2$ having a sampling frequency of 200 Hz. I need the magnitude and phase responses when the two filters are cascaded. Is it correct to convert these filters in the s-domain then study the response of $G_1(s)G_2(s)$ or do I need to rescale $G_2$ in the z-domain with a 10-kHz sampling frequency before analyzing the product of the two transfer functions? Thank you.

Comment: How do handle the mismatch in sample rate, zero order hold?

Comment: I am surprised that nobody has answered this one yet ? Have you considered getting onto FB just for Ray Ridley's "Power Supply Design Center" group ? It has a very high signal to noise ratio. Stack Exchange is also a great group, typically but it's good to have options and there may be a bit too much mod er ation here? I have not seen you there. There was also a group on Linked In but the FB group works better as for posting pictures and papers and visuals. boB